# Is there a way to make a radio button uncheckable?

Tags: html, radio-button, checked

I was wondering if there's any way that I can make a HTML radio button impossible to check. Like, when the user presses it, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Comment: Would it be the sole button or part of a set? Because if it is marked as `disabled` using that attribute let's say and it's part of a set, the color will not match the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute.

```
<input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="email" disabled>
```